# How can I style bottom section of screen In REACT NATIVE where minimize, home and back buttons are placed?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, mobile

[image: bottom section screen]

I want to style the section in the image above, of my App to look exactly like the rest of the screen of my App but couldn't find how to do that, can anyone help me out, please?

e.g: giving it backgroundColor of #fff and color of #222
So that my app screen looks the same from top to bottom.

Thanks as you help me out!!

PS: I styled statusBar with built-in React Native API but couldn't find that of the bottom section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found out that it can be achieved by configuring app.json in the root folder of the project.

```json
"androidNavigationBar": {
   "barStyle": "dark-content",
   "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
}
```

Full options and documentation can be found [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#name)